# C compile error: unknown type name 'node'

Tags: c

The compiler gives the following error with the code below, at the location of the added comment:

> error: unknown type name 'node'

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int info;
    node *sig; //<-- error: unknown type name 'node'
} nodeL;

int main(void) {
    nodeL n;
    printf("%x\n", n.info);

    return 0;
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Your struct name is `nodo` and you declare `node`.

Comment: This is a simple typographical error, so it should be closed.

Comment: It seems that everyone focused on the (now fixed) nodo/node typo, while the actual problem is that `sig` should be of the type `struct node`, or `nodeL` with a forward declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You must keep in mind that C compiler don't know what is node or nodo (you typed it wrong in the struct name probably), it's not a C primary type.
At this point nodo is a struct type and you must "say" it to the compiler, like:

```
typedef struct nodo
{
    int info;
    struct nodo *sig; 
} nodeL;
```

The atribute `nodo *sig;` inside the struct declares a member sig that is a defined pointer to the struct type.

Answer (score -1):

```
typedef struct nodo
{
    int info;
    struct nodo *sig; // Rather than: node *sig;
} nodeL;
```

It looks like your structure name `node` is what you are referencing inside the structure.  `nodo` not `node`.

Perhaps there is a mis-understanding that `nodo` (or `node`) is a C type. It is not a type.  However `struct nodo` is defined in the question code.

Comment: your answer is just code with no explanation as to why you've changed what you've changed