# What are the two names of the struct, and why can't I put the bottom one as a data type inside it?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have the following struct defined with the typedef keyword:

```
typedef struct{
  int data;
  NODE *next;
}NODE;
```

It gives me the following error when compiling:

> error: unknown type name ‘NODE’
> I looked it up, and found this stack overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202536/error-unknown-type-name-node), which said I should change it to

```
typedef struct n{
  int data;
  n *next;
}NODE;
```

I have two question about this.

First, what is the `n`? I thought `NODE` was the name of the struct, so is that a second name?

The second is, why can I put the `n` as a data type, but not `NODE`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [typedef struct vs struct definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions)

Comment: Even if it's related, it doens't answer my questions directly, no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NODE` is not the name of the struct.  It's a `typedef`, i.e. an alias for the struct.  In the first case, the struct is unnamed.  In the second case, the struct is named `struct n`.

The reason you can't use `NODE` inside of the struct is because that name hasn't been defined yet at the time it is used.  So you need to use the actual name of the struct (which *is* defined) in order to create a pointer to it.

Also note that the `struct` keyword is required in C when using the struct's name, i.e.:

```
struct n *next;
```

Comment: why isn't NODE defined yet?

Comment: @DuarteArribas Because it appears in the file after `next`.

Answer (score 0):

With your combined structure definition and `typedef`, the name `NODE` is not yet defined at the location when you try to use it.

```
typedef struct{
  int data;
  NODE *next; // name NODE used here
}NODE;        // name NODE defined here
```

You can do the typedef before the structure definition to use it for a pointer.

```
typedef struct n NODE; // NODE defined as incomplete type

struct n {
  int data;
  NODE *next; // use as pointer is OK
}; 
// from here NODE is completely defined
```

But you cannot define a variable or structure field of type `NODE` before the structure is really defined.

```
typedef struct n NODE;

#if 0
// does not work because NODE is an incomplete type here
struct wrapper {
  NODE node;
};
#endif

// using a pointer to an incomplete type is OK
struct n {
  int data;
  NODE *next;
}; 

// works
struct wrapper {
  NODE node;
};
```

---

You can use

```
typedef struct n{ // type "struct n" known here
  int data;
  struct n *next; // use known type
}NODE; // type alias NODE known here
```

because the type `struct n` is already known when you use it for the pointer.

Note that in C you have to use `struct n *next` (in contrast to C++).